# Android: TouchListener of children of CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-coordinatorlayout

If I try to set a OnTouchListener on children of a CoordinatorLayout 
they never get called.

Please what am I missing here?

**I have tried returning true and false** form onToch(), I have tried using requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent, but no success.

---

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordiator_layout_in_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nav_view">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/coordiator_layout_in_main"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"   
       app:layout_behavior="com.material.widget.MyFloatingActionButtonBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then I do:

```
 findViewById(R.id.relative).setOnTouchListener(new      View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            foo();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

it never gets called.

What am I missing here?

Comment: **Stop signing your posts "thanks, LISA"**. Myself and others have been consistently editing that out of your question for *years* now. Stop it.

Comment: @Lisa Anne, did you find the answer?